# Is it possible to split a Dynamo Db table into more tables (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Currently I'm working with a client on an IOT project involving sensors. Currently all their data is being put into one table. This data is coming from multiple sensor nodes. They want one table for every sensor node. I want to know if through AWS Dynamo Db it is possible to split the data into multiple separate tables using the hash key from an existing table. I have looked into GSI's and LSI's but this still isn't exactly what my client wants. Also would having multiple table even be more effective than using and LSI or GSI ? I am new to nosql and dynamo db so all the help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB does not support splitting data into multiple tables - in the sense that DynamoDB operations themselves, including the atomic conditional checks, can't be performed across table boundaries. But that doesn't mean that splitting data across tables is incompatible with DynamoDB - just that you have to add the logic in your application.

You can definitely do so as long as the data from the different sensors is *isolated* enough. A more common scenario would be to split data into multiple tables across time boundaries in order to discard/archive old data, since DynamoDB already makes it possible and convenient to handle partitioning your data with hash keys and global secondary indexes.

In the end I would say that there is no need and it doesn't make sense to split data into multiple tables on the hash key - but it can be done. However, a more useful case is to split data into multiple tables on some other attribute of the data that is not part of the hash, or range key (such as the time-series data example).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. As i said I am new to nosql is it possible to store millions of rows in one dynamo db table and have it still query quickly if the table is indexed on the hash key. Each index (sensor) could have up to 102,000 rows stored (this will be over 2 years). The web application that will be pulling this data will be generating historical graphs for each sensor. So what I'm essentially asking will it be just as efficient to store this quantity of data in one indexed table as it would be to store it in multiple. Thank you again for your first response.